# Share Tethered connection to other devices

Tags: networking, internet-connection, raspbian, sharing

What I want to do is the following:
Tether my android device's internet connection to a Raspberry Pi (USB cable). Then via ethernet cable connect the Raspberry to a router. Other devices are then connected to the router for internet connection.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

connect Raspberry PI to wifi with standard tools

```
echo 1>net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Pick a private ip range like 192.168.0.1
set the lan IP address.
configure the dhcp server.

```
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {

  option routers 192.168.0.1;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
  authoritative ;
  range 192.168.3.2 192.168.3.255;
  default-lease-time 14400;
  max-lease-time 172800;
}
```

save and exit
go into named.conf
find 
allow-query { 127.0.0.1;};
change by adding 192.168.0.1/24; after 127.0.0.1
save and exit
restart dhcp server and named serivce, and it should work.